# (That or These)/(This or Those) for Compound Subjects?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I understand that compound subjects when joined with "and" are plural:

- The car and house are for sale.

But what about for the "that/this" preceding the compound subjects?

- That/Those house, car, and street belong to me.

Right now, I'm thinking it should be "those" because of the compound subject "house, car, and street"...but it sounds weird to me in my head also thinking it might be "that" because to refer to the first subject "house."

Also, what about for something like this?

- People will go far in life with (that/those) desire and motivation.

(It's a compound subject "desire and motivation" so grammatically it probably should be "those," but it sounds like it could be "that.")

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you wonder if that or those can be an answer to the example sentence.

That house, car, and street belong to me. (X)

Those house, car, and street belong to me. (X)

Those sentences are not clear and look unnatural.

The house, the car, and the street belong to me (O)

Those - the house, the car, the street - belong to me (O)

The house, the car, the street: those belong to me (O)

Again your examples are below.

'That' is used for singular noun, so you can't use that here.

If you wanna use it, it should be "That house, that car, (and) that street ~"

'Those' is used for plural nouns.

'Those' is usually used to describe **a** plural noun: Those houses are beautiful or Those boys, girls, dogs, and cats are coming here.

Back to your question: Those houses, cars, and streets belong to me.

Comment: I know I can use "the," but the question was is "that or those" correct for situations like these when the subject is compounded with "and." There are situations when you would want to use a "specific" that/those rather than the.

Comment: I cannot agree with this. By changing the sentence to "Those houses, cars and streets..." you are now pluralising the subject, even though it was initially singular. The assumption is that there is only; one house, one car and one street.